# Fastest mixing Markov chain on a graph — derivation of optimal conditions

Tags: graph-theory, convex-optimization, markov-chains, duality-theorems, semidefinite-programming

I am currently reading a classic paper, [Fastest Mixing Markov Chain on a Graph](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/fmmc.pdf), by Boyd & Diaconis & Xiao. I have problem understanding how the optimal conditions can be derived in Section 4.2.

The paper first formulates the original problem into a semidefinite progamming problem. Note $A \preceq B$ means $B-A$ is positive semidefinite.

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\min \quad & s\\
\textrm{s.t.} \quad & -SI \preceq P-\frac{1}{n}\textbf{1}\textbf{1}^{T} \preceq SI \\
  & P\geq 0, \hspace{0.1cm} P\textbf{1}=\textbf{1},\hspace{0.1cm} P=P^{T} \\
  & P_{i,j}=0 , \hspace{0.1cm} (i,j) \not \in E  
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Then it derives its dual problem: 
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\max \quad & 1^{T}z\\
\textrm{s.t.} \quad & Y\textbf{1}=0,\sum_{i=1}^{n} |\lambda_i(Y)| \leq 1\\
  & \frac{z_i+z_j}{2} \leq Y_{i,j}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
After proving strong duality, in section 4.2, the paper gives the optimal conditions (KKT) but omits the derivation. I understand the part of primal feasibility, dual feasibility, and the first equation in complementary slackness must be true, but I don't understand how the other equations in the complementary slackness section can be derived:
$$Y^{*}=Y_{+}^{*}-Y_{-}^{*}, \hspace{0.1cm} 0 \preceq Y_{+}^{*} , \hspace{0.1cm} 0 \preceq Y_{-}^{*}$$ 
$$P^{*}Y_{+}^{*}=\mu(P^{*})Y_{+}^{*}, \hspace{0.1cm} P^{*}Y_{-}^{*}=-\mu(P^{*})Y_{-}^{*}, \hspace{0.1cm} Tr(Y_{+}^{*})+Tr(Y_{-}^{*})=1$$

Here $\mu(P^{*})$ refers to the second largest eigenvalue modulus of $P^{*}$, the optimal transition matrix. $Y_{+}^{*}$ and $Y_{-}^{*}$ are the positive semidefinite and negative semidefinite parts of $Y^{*}$, which I don't really understand. The paper says the derivation is similar to the ideas contained in this paper: https://cs.nyu.edu/media/publications/TR1991-566.pdf, but I'm not sure which part of the paper to focus on, and there doesn't seem to be a discussion regarding the positive/negative semidefinite part of a matrix. Please let me know if you know how the optimal conditions might be derived. Thank you!